# How to scan for QR codes on button press?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, camera-view

I am using the code provided by https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code to make my own scanning app. But I like my scanning to occur on button press. Now for this I put the `viewDidLoad()` part from the tutorial into its own function:

```
func cameraScanningLayer(){
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        failed();
        return;
    }


    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        // need to scan barcode + QRcode
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    // Previewlayer with camera
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
    previewLayer.frame = viewForLayer.bounds;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    viewForLayer.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer);

    captureSession.startRunning();
}
```

And a button action calls the function:

```
func buttonScanAction() {
    print("Scan")
    scanEnabled = true // like to use some kind of bool/switch
    self.cameraScanningLayer()
}
```

The problems I have are:

1) On load the camera is not in view

2) After the button is pressed the camera is in view but it always scans automatically

So I thought of using a global:

```
var scanEnabled: Bool = false
```

Then, when the button is clicked, set it to true and the scanning is enabled.

For reference here is a sketch:

[image]

**EDIT**
my quick fix which might not be the right way to do it.

I replaced the

```
 let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput() {...} else {
            failed()
            return
        }
```

and put it between an if statement

```
if (scanEnabled == true) {

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
            // to use them both wwe need to skip AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]
            scanEnabled = false
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Author of that tutorial here. My method was to use a dedicated scanning view controller, but I guess you want to unify that with your existing view controller – and that's fine. Both approaches work.

If you want to show the camera interface all the time (even when not actively recognising QR codes) then your plan to use a boolean to track whether scanning is enabled is a good one. My example code has a `foundCode()` method that gets called, and also calls `dismissViewControllerAnimated()` when codes are found.

In your version, you need to make `foundCode()` do all the work of stopping the scane, handling the dismissal, etc. You can then add a check for your `scanEnabled` boolean in one place.

Something like this ought to do it:

```
func foundCode(code: String) {
    if scanCode == true {
        print(code)

        captureSession.stopRunning()
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If you wanted to, you could move the `scanCode == true` check up to `didOutputMetadataObjects` to save the unnecessary method call.

Comment: tx for your tutorial. I will check if i can put your code suggestion (using the foundcode function) to work in my "messy" setup. I edited/updated my original quesiton with some code which seems to do the job. 
BTW: i notice the metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode] adding types to the array doesn't seem to work only the first ObjectType seems to recognize the input. In my case i have qr-code and barcode which i want to scan.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @alex for this question. I also use the excellent class created by twostraws (Very useful Paul, thank you so much) and also needed to implement code scan reading with only the action of a button. My solution was the following:

I define `metadataOutput` as a global variable and only in the button action do I integrate them as a delegate:

```
var metadataOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput!
```

In `viewDidLoad` method:

```
metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
    captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
    // Was removed this line: metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
} else {
    failed()
    return
}

func buttonScanAction() {
    print("Scan")
    metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
}
```

When I change my view I stop the camera and remove the delegate like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
    }
    metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(nil, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
}
```