# QR Scan on Button Press Only

Tags: swift, uibutton, qr-code

I have used similar code to the one shown in the following question: [How to scan for QR codes on button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291010/how-to-scan-for-qr-codes-on-button-press).
I can now have the camera preview active all the time and only scan when my button is pressed. 
My problem is, I have found that if I (accidentally) push the button before being focussed on a QR code, the reader will automatically scan the next QR code it see's. 
Is there any way I can account for any accidental button presses and only scan the QR code when I have one in view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching, I've finally worked out a solution...

I've basically created a button that will appear over my camera preview should a QR code be detected. This button will be hidden by default:

```
scanButton.isHidden = true
```

Then used the following code to show the button only if a QR code is found. This is used in conjunction with code to highlight the QR code when found.

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            scanButton.isHidden = false
            view.bringSubview(toFront: scanButton)
            data = metadataObj.stringValue
        }
```

The action for the scanButton is then:

```
@IBAction func scanQRButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Scanned QR: " + (data))
    captureSession?.stopRunning()
}
```

I will then add a segue function to pass this data to another view controller where I can work with it.

Hope this makes sense and helps someone else avoid all of the head scratching I have done!